# Network teaming configuration

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, ethernet, bonding

How to configure the teaming network?

On our redhat machines we configured as the following the teaming network

On each machine we have two links - ens1f5 and ens1f6
And we add the team0 file to control them

My question is- is it enough to create these 3 files?
So in case one of the links will failed then other link will be active ?

**Or**

We must to enable the teamdctl service in order team will works

For now **teamdctl** service is disable ( but teamd rpm is installed )

```
rpm -qa | grep teamd
teamd-1.17-5.el7.x86_64


teamdctl nm-team state
Device "nm-team" does not exist
```

the files under **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts** are:

```
DEVICE=team0
DEVICETYPE=Team
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=102.13.16.19
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=102.13.16.3
TEAM_CONFIG='{"runner": {"name": "activebackup"}, "link_watch": {"name": "ethtool"}}'



DEVICE=ens1f5
HWADDR=28:df:31:30:d7:4a
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
TEAM_PORT_CONFIG='{"prio": 100}'



DEVICE=ens1f6
HWADDR=28:df:31:30:d2:4d
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
TEAM_PORT_CONFIG='{"prio": 100}'
```

Reference - https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-configure-network-teaming-in-linux/

Comment: Usually those configurations are not enough. e.g. The configuration also has to be done on the switching side.

Comment: what you mean on switch side ?

Comment: what I am asking was - if we creating the 3 files , and restart the network service , dose teaming is active and functional ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to `apt install libteam-dev` to get the 'nm-team' device to show. Strange but even though Kunbuntu 20.04 has everything else in that startup Reference guide above, I was also following, it didn't have that. I also installed `apt install libteam-utils` to get the `teamdctl` command to work.

Nothing 'switch side' was needed. However, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, doesnt exist on _buntus. It is under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` as 'team-slave-enp0s25.nmconnection' for example, because it uses the newer nmcli and network-manager.